# Can Kerdi board be painted instead of tiled?

Tags: board, kerdi

can Kerdi board be painted? I want to use it on the walls in my bathroom instead of sheet rock.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can paint over Kerdi board but you will need to give it a light coat of joint compound and do a little sanding.

Comment: Painter here, that's what I was going to say, you can paint anything if paint will stick, prime it first and do enough fairing... (joint compound, bondo, etc)